# Running yo meanjs hangs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean

I'm getting hangs indefinitely at "This could take a few minutes" when running "yo meanjs". When I try running grunt it fails, same with npm start.

I'm on Win 8.1 and have the latest Node and Mongo installed. Any ideas?

This is the error log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\John\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.3.12
3 info using node@v4.2.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle mean@0.0.0~prestart: mean@0.0.0
6 silly lifecycle mean@0.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle mean@0.0.0~start: mean@0.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle mean@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle mean@0.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\source\meantutorial\mean\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\K-3D 0.8.0.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\.meteor\;C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\npm
10 verbose lifecycle mean@0.0.0~start: CWD: C:\source\meantutorial\mean
11 silly lifecycle mean@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'grunt' ]
12 silly lifecycle mean@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 99  signal: null
13 info lifecycle mean@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: mean@0.0.0 start: `grunt`
14 verbose stack Exit status 99
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:232:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
15 verbose pkgid mean@0.0.0
16 verbose cwd C:\source\meantutorial\mean
17 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\John\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
19 error node v4.2.2
20 error npm  v3.3.12
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error mean@0.0.0 start: `grunt`
22 error Exit status 99
23 error Failed at the mean@0.0.0 start script 'grunt'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the mean package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     grunt
23 error You can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls mean
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message mentions that running grunt failed; This hints that there is something wrong with your grunt installation. What is the output when you run `grunt` *after `yo meanjs` fails*?

If grunt is not working, try installing grunt-cli; `npm install -g grunt-cli` (hint; make sure your user has adequate permissions).

Run `grunt` again. If it succeeds, run `bower install` and you are ready (if bower is not installed, install it by running `npm install -g bower`).